# Frequency count for Comma delimited categories within a column

Tags: r, count, frequency

I have a data frame in R. the data frame has multiple rows and multiple columns. One of the columns has comma separated values for different vehicle makes such as Toyota, Honda, etc. I want to calculate the frequency of the comma separated values and output the top three values in terms of frequency of occurrence for each row.
Here is the data-set looks like:

```
Zip                   Make
12325 Toyota, Honda, Toyota, Mitsubishi, Mercedes
85271 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Toyota,Volvo,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan, Nissan 
56098 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Chevrolet,Acura,Chevrolet,Chevrolet, Honda
```

Here is the output I want

[Output appended in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkr0W.png)

Can anyone help with the actual R code based on the example?

Comment: This is not the way to do this. You want your data in a tidy format so that you can easily manipulate and do analysis on. There is no way to do analysis the way your data set currently is, and _especially_ the way you would like it to come out. 
Please first provide `dput()` of your dataset and post it here

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `tidyverse`. `dt_final` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Separate the comma
dt2 <- dt %>% separate_rows(Make)

# Calculate the frequency
dt3 <- dt2 %>% count(Zip, Make) 

# Prepare the Frequency column
dt4 <- dt3 %>%
  mutate(n = paste0("(", n, ")")) %>%
  unite(Frequency, Make, n, sep = " ") %>%
  group_by(Zip) %>%
  summarise(Frequency = paste0(Frequency, collapse = ", "))

# Prepare the Top 3 Make column
dt5 <- dt3 %>%
  group_by(Zip) %>%
  mutate(Rank = dense_rank(n)) %>%
  filter(Rank <= 3) %>%
  arrange(Zip, Rank, Make) %>%
  select(Zip, Make) %>%
  summarise(`Top 3 Make (per frequency)` = paste0(Make, collapse = ", "))

# Join the results
dt_final <- reduce(list(dt, dt4, dt5), left_join, by = "Zip")

dt_final
#     Zip                                                                       Make
# 1 12325                                Toyota, Honda, Toyota, Mitsubishi, Mercedes
# 2 85271 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Toyota,Volvo,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan, Nissan
# 3 56098  Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Chevrolet,Acura,Chevrolet,Chevrolet, Honda
#                                                         Frequency
# 1             Honda (1), Mercedes (1), Mitsubishi (1), Toyota (2)
# 2                    Honda (2), Nissan (4), Toyota (4), Volvo (1)
# 3 Acura (1), Chevrolet (3), Honda (2), Mitsubishi (1), Toyota (2)
#                    Top 3 Make (per frequency)
# 1         Honda, Mercedes, Mitsubishi, Toyota
# 2                Volvo, Honda, Nissan, Toyota
# 3 Acura, Mitsubishi, Honda, Toyota, Chevrolet
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Zip                   Make
12325 'Toyota, Honda, Toyota, Mitsubishi, Mercedes'
                 85271 'Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Toyota,Volvo,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan, Nissan' 
                 56098 'Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Chevrolet,Acura,Chevrolet,Chevrolet, Honda'",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tidy the data first before you do any manipulation and summing.

Your Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(Zip =c(12325, 85271, 56098), Make = c("Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Mercedes", "Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Toyota,Volvo,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan", "Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Chevrolet,Acura,Chevrolet,Chevrolet,Honda"))
```

Turn Make into Character so we can split it

```
df$Make <- as.character(df$Make)
```

Import libraries

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)
```

Split out each column by comma, and create a matrix of different makes, and then turn it into a dataframe. Then name the columns, and assign the zip column from your dataframe to our new cleaner one.

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$Make, ",", max(unlist(lapply(strsplit(df$Make, ","), length)))))


names(df2) <- paste0("car_", 1:ncol(df2))

df2$zip <- df$Zip
```

**Inspect:**

```
> df2
   car_1 car_2  car_3      car_4     car_5  car_6     car_7     car_8  car_9 car_10 car_11   zip
1 Toyota Honda Toyota Mitsubishi  Mercedes                                                 12325
2 Toyota Honda Toyota      Honda    Toyota Toyota     Volvo    Nissan Nissan Nissan Nissan 85271
3 Toyota Honda Toyota Mitsubishi Chevrolet  Acura Chevrolet Chevrolet  Honda               56098
```

Now we want to tidy it up. We can gather the columns to turn it from wide format to long. Then we replace empties with NA, and filter them out. We then remove the `car` column that we created. After that we'll group by `zip` and `Make` and `summarise` which shows the count of each `Make` by `zip`. Lastly we arrange it descending by number.

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  gather(car, Make, -zip) %>%
  replace(. == "", NA) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Make)) %>%
  select(-car) %>%
  group_by(zip, Make) %>%
  summarise(number = n()) %>%
  arrange(zip, desc(number))
```

Last thing we do is we can create a new df called `top3`, and we can slice it to grab just the first 3 rows from each grouping (of `zip` and `Make`). Since we've arranged it descending, we will get the top 3 makes by zip code with this dataframe.

```
top3 <- df3 %>%
  slice(1:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on the output format as shown in the screenshot, here is a base R solution (no additional R libraries):

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Zip Make
     12325 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Mercedes
     85271 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Toyota,Volvo,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan
     56098 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Chevrolet,Acura,Chevrolet,Chevrolet,Honda", 
     header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$Frequency <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(df$Make, ","), function(x)
    paste0(apply(as.data.frame(table(x)), 1, paste, collapse = "("), ")")),
    paste, collapse = ",");

df$top <- sapply(lapply(strsplit(df$Make, ","), function(x)
    names(table(x)[order(-table(x))][1:3])),
    paste, collapse = ",");

df;
#    Zip
#1 12325
#2 85271
#3 56098
#                                                                       Make
#1                                   Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Mercedes
#2 Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Toyota,Volvo,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan,Nissan
#3  Toyota,Honda,Toyota,Mitsubishi,Chevrolet,Acura,Chevrolet,Chevrolet,Honda
#                                               Frequency                    top
#1           Honda(1),Mercedes(1),Mitsubishi(1),Toyota(2)  Toyota,Honda,Mercedes
#2                  Honda(2),Nissan(4),Toyota(4),Volvo(1)    Nissan,Toyota,Honda
#3 Acura(1),Chevrolet(3),Honda(2),Mitsubishi(1),Toyota(2) Chevrolet,Honda,Toyota
```

Comment: We got the same results except for the last column. I think the OP would like to keep all the top 3 make even there is a tie, so only slicing the table output may not be enough.

Comment: @www Yes, you're right. Dealing with ties is a bit more work. I cut a corner there, to balance between code simplicity and reproducing OP's exact expected output.

Comment: I think you provided a great solution and I agree that it is important to maintain code simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, consider the comment of @Matt W. about organizing your data frame in a more appropriated way, having a list inside of a cell usually is a symptom of a bad design.

Nevertheless, let's assume that your data frame is df, then:

```
# iterate over all the cells in the Make column of the dataframe
top3 <- unlist(lapply(df$Make, function(cell) {
  # convert the cell string to a vector
  cars <- unlist(strsplit(cell, ','))
  # count how many of each different type are
  carFreq <- unlist(lapply(unique(cars), function(c) sum(c == cars)))
  # fix the name of carFreq
  names(carFreq) <- unique(cars)
  # return a string with the top 3
  paste0(names(sort(carFreq, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]), collapse = ', ')
}))

# finally put the extra column in the data frame    
df <- cbind(df, top3)
```

There is no need for a library.

Comment: Thank you all. I was actually able to solve it also just using sqldf package. Adding the code here from my end:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for sharing the answers. I was actually able to solve it also just on my end by using sqldf package. BB2 is the original data-set that contain zip and Concatenated make columns. Here is the code

> D1 <- strsplit(BB2$MakeConcat, split = ",")
>   View(BB2)
>   D2<- data.frame(zip= rep(BB2$zip, sapply(D1, length)),MakeConcat=unlist(D1))
>   View(D2)
>   D3<- sqldf("select zip, count(MakeConcat) as count2, MakeConcat from D2 group by zip, MakeConcat order by zip desc")
>    View(D3)
>   D4 <- mydf[order(D3$count2, D3$zip, decreasing = TRUE),]
>   D4 <- D3[order(D3$count2, D3$zip, decreasing = TRUE),]
>   D4_x<- D4[ave(D4$count, D4$zip, FUN = seq_along) <= 3,]
>   View(D4_x)
>   Final<- sqldf("SELECT zip, upper(GROUP_CONCAT(MakeConcat)) as MakeConcat FROM D4_x group by zip")

Comment: If you indent each line by 4 spaces then SO will format this for you.